# Export 'Switch' was not found in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs

how can i solve this problem
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/App.js 20:37-43

export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)

I want help to solve this problem

Comment: Either use older version or change code to work with the new one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 9):

export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

// Use `<Routes>` instead of `<Switch>`

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
      <Link to='/home'>Home</Link>
      <Link to='/about'>About</Link>

      <Routes>
      <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>} />
      <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />
    
      </Routes>
      </Router>
```

This will Solve your Error;

Answer (score 5):

If you are using react-router-dom version V6.0.0 then it will not work, so downgrade the version of the react-router-dom to be below V6 and run

```
    npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

or otherwise checkout the new version for new updates.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the new version of react-router-dom.
*Switch* has been replaced with *Routes* and some other things have been changed too.
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 2):

If you are using react-router-dom version V6.0.0 then it will not work, so downgrade the version of the react-router-dom to be below V6 and run

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { BrowserRouter,Switch,Route } from 'react-router-dom';

Have try with this don't change BrowseRouter as Router

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
        <Route path='/home' Component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/about' Component={Aboutus}/>
        <Route path='/youtube' Component={Youtube}/>
        <Route path='/blog' Component={Blogs}/>
        <Route path='/gallery' Component={Gallery}/>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </header>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Switch" use routes in app.js file.

```html
Example:-

    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
    import SignUpLocationStepOne from './components/signup/SignUpLocationStepOne';
    import Header from './components/header/Header';
    import Navigation from './components/header/Navigation';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUpLocationStepOne} />
            <Route path="/" exact component={Header} />
          </Routes>
    
        </div>
      </Router>
      );
    }
```